# Automate process to link Google Adwords account with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-ads-api, google-cloud-iam

Note - Below all these points I am doing manually, I want to make it automatically with programming.

I have several questions regarding "google-cloud-iam"

Are these below points are possible programmatically via "google-cloud-iam" any type of API?

1. Do Link Google Adwords account with Google analytics (User is using the same Gmail account for AdWords and Analytics account)
2. Create a project in the cloud google console, enable "Analytics API", create a service account, and download the P12 Key at the server-side or client-side.
3. Add Service account id in Google Analytics user management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feasibility and references:

1. You can create the link between Google Ads and Analytics by executing the `insert` method of the `entityAdWordsLinks` resource: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/google-ads-links

2.The Google Cloud Resource Manager https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects ,  https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/create

3. The Google Analytics Management API allows for programmatic management of user permissions: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/user-management